# Laravel make view request doesn't change in the URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I am using middleware to redirect a user if they don't meet certain criteria (haven't accepted terms and conditions!). They are redirected to `/terms`.

**Middleware:**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->terms === 0) {
            return redirect()->route('getTerms');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

The above works perfectly.

Once the user 'accepts' the terms and conditions, I want to redirect them to the homepage (which currently works), however, the URL doesn't change. It still stays on `/terms`, even though they're on the homepage.

**Controller 'accept terms':**

```
$user = User::find(Auth::id());
$user->terms = 1;
$user->save();

return view('home');
```

The reason I *need* the URL to redirect back to `/home` is because I have a layout condition, that I need a view to be included when the user is ***not on*** the `/term` url.

**Layout condition:**

```
 @if(!Request::is('terms'))
     @include('layouts.check')
 @endif
```

Why isn't the `return view('home);` working the same as it is in other functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning the "home" view from your "accept terms" action, return a redirect to the actual home route.

```
return redirect()->route('home');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirects

Comment: Works perfectly, I can't believe I overlooked a redirect! Many thanks @LorenzSchaef.